# Why the set_gid bit in /var/log/tor/?

Tags: security

On debian-based systems, the tor logging directory has the permissions

```
$ ls -ald /var/log/tor/
drwxr-s--- ... /var/log/tor/
```

Why is this so? Is this a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setgid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories), setting the set_gid bit on directories has a different meaning than with files:

> Setting the `setgid` permission on a directory ("`chmod g+s`") causes new
>   files and subdirectories created within it to **inherit its group ID**,
>   rather than the primary group ID of the user who created the file

From this, it seems as though it is intended and ok.